# Wordpress: error in callback function when applying filter to customize page title

Tags: wordpress, filter, callback, hook, page-title

I have some templates where I need to customize the page title according to user selection. I have added a filter hook to 'wp_title' tag following Codex docs but when the filter is applied I'm receiving a warning, I'd say an error, regarding parameters in the callback function declaration:

Warning:  Missing argument 4 for buildPageTitle() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.../blog/wp-content/themes/.../inc/my_functions.php on line 2

my_functions.php

```
1  <?php
2  function buildPageTitle($sep, $echo, $seplocation, $brand) {
3    return $brand.$sep;
4  }
5  ...
```

Template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: By brand-countries
*/

$brandLabel = get_query_var('brand');
require_once('inc/dbConn.php');
require_once('inc/get_brand_data.php');
require_once('inc/my_functions.php');

add_filter('wp_title', 'buildPageTitle', 10, 4);
apply_filters('wp_title', $sep, false, $seplocation, $brand);
get_header();
?>
```

I can solve the problem declaring $brand var as global in the buildPageTitle() function but I prefer to pass it as a parameter as in other templates different vars will be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a wrong idea how WordPress filters work. There is a function `wp_title()` and a filter `wp_title`. You call the function, which does some work to create a title, and then passes its output to the filter, so other code can further customize the result.

The function and the filter do not necessarily use the same arguments. For the function `wp_title()` you can pass the separator, whether to echo the title or not, and the separator location. The filter can get the title as `wp_title()` has created it, the separator and the separator location. When setting up the filter hook (via `add_filter()`) you specify how many arguments you need: 1 (the default), 2 or 3. You can't get more than three arguments because `wp_title()` does not pass more than three arguments to the `wp_title` filter.

So you should not have to call `apply_filters()` yourself. You call `wp_title()` (probably in your `header.php` template file, and this function calls the filter itself.

If you want to access your `brand` variable you should either put it in a global variable or let your `buildPageTitle()` function call some other function that will return it. What strategy to use depends on your situation. Can you tell more about the different templates and the title formats you want to use there?

Comment: Jan: Thanks a lot for your help. I called apply_filters() because I understood from the documentation that it'll allow me pass additional params. Finally I used global vars; the title format is something like: DIOR stores locator, DIOR stores locator in FRANCE and so on where brands, countries and cities vary depending on user selection